# Java Async MongoDB driver and RxJava2 Observables

Tags: java, mongodb, observable, rx-java2, asyncmongo

I'm studying reactive programming with RxJava2 and I have a question about its usage with an async database driver like MongoDB.

If I use blocking MongoDB driver to get a collection the approach would be this:

```
public class MyDao{
   ...
   public Document getFirstDocument(String collectionName){
      MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
      return collection.find().first();
   }
}



public class MyService {
   ...
   public Observable<Document> getFirstOf(String collectionName){
       return Observable.just(myDao.getFirstDocument(collectionName)); 
   }
}
```

Instead, working with the async Driver of MongoDB, my return type for a read operation is a void (and not a Document, or a Future)with a callback method inside, for example:

```
collection.find().first(
        (document, throwable) -> {
            myService.myCallback(document);
        }
);
```

So, how can I pass my Observable Documents to MyService?

```
public class MyDao{
   ...
   public void getFirstDocument(String collectionName){
      MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
      collection.find().first(
        (document, throwable) -> {
            //SOME SORT OF CALLBACK
        }
     );
   }
}



public class MyService {
   ...
   public Observable<Document> getFirstOf(String collectionName){
       return ??????? 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `Observable.just()` in

```
public Observable<Document> getFirstOf(String collectionName){
    return Observable.just(myDao.getFirstDocument(collectionName)); 
}
```

it equals to next code

```
public Observable<Document> getFirstOf(String collectionName){
    Document doc = myDao.getFirstDocument(collectionName);
    return Observable.just(doc); 
}
```

You can notice that it's not `async` code and request to DB is performed on calling thread. To make that code `async` you need to rewrite it like that

```
public Observable<Document> getFirstOf(String collectionName){
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> myDao.getFirstDocument(collectionName)); 
}
```

If you are using `async` MongoDB driver and would like to wrap it in `Observable`, you can write in that way

```
public Observable<Document> getFirstDocument(String collectionName) {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
        collection.find().first((document, throwable) -> {
            if(document != null) {
                emitter.onNext(document);
                emitter.onComplete();
            } else if(throwable != null) {
                emitter.onError(throwable);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Are the two code snippet equivalent in terms of performance? I mean, is the fromCallable an equivalent turn-around if you don't have async DB drivers?

Comment: @AlexMawashi, it depends on async DB driver. I think that main different is that in case of `Observable.fromCallable()` you need manually switch on background thread (using `susbcribeOn()`) and get result back on main thread (using `observeOn()`). In case of async DB driver that work is done by driver. Don't think that the performance is so different.